# If a list of strings contains in a pandas series of strings? and how to extract the match string from a list? what's the best practice way?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a two pandas Series with Name of movies and a list of words. I want to check all entries in the list of words which contains in Series or not? and what's that word?

encoders DataFrame

```
full
0   r00t
1   YIFY
2   Silence
3   RMTeam
4   PSA
5   RARBG
6   Ohys-Raws
```

final DataFrame

```
  FilePath
0    All About Eve (1950) (1080p BluRay x265 Silence).mkv
1    Anatomy of a Murder (1959) Criterion (1080p BluRay x265 r00t).mkv
2    Black Orpheus (1959).mkv
3    Casablanca (1942) 70th Anniv (1080p BluRay x265 10bit Tigole).mkv
```

my code:

```
encoder_match=[]
index=0
for x in final.FilePath: 
    if len(encoder_match)<index:
        encoder_match.append('')
    else:
        pass
    for y in encoders.full:
        if y in x:
            encoder_match.append(y)
        else:
            continue
    index+=1
                    
encoder_match
```

and
why doesn't this code work?

```
[x for x in encoders.full if final.FilePath.str.contains(x)]

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

what's the best practice way?
thank you

Comment: Why is this in pandas at all?  It's much easier to work with strings as plain Python lists.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).